# How do I make a on site pop up?

Tags: javascript

I have an adblock script on my site, that registers, when people uses adblock. My problem is now, that I want a pop up to appear on the site, when it finds a user with adblock. The "hard" about this, is that I don't want a regular pop up, like this:

```
var w = window.open('', '', 'width=350,height=100,resizeable,scrollbars');
w.document.write('text');
w.document.close();
```

This code ends up as a "regular" pop up.

I want a on the site pop up, if you know what i mean.
I have an example of it [here](http://i.gyazo.com/a2f51f2d20db7aff9f390bcdc92c7d88.png).

Comment: You're not talking about popup anymore but modal windows (divs with an overlay that takes all the page)

Comment: http://bootboxjs.com/#

Comment: Did the contribution below help, Benjamin? It is currently unresponded to.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to create a modal dialog.

You can use any modal library by searching for "modal javascript" on your favorite search engine. A few have mentioned interesting libraries in the comments on your question.

Making your own modal is also easy:

Create the `<div>` with the content you want and give it a style such as:

```
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -50%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    /* ... */
}
```

Instead of the code you show above, simply call `$(elt).show()` if you are using jQuery, or `elt.style.display="block";` in pure DOM js.